# What wires do I need to connect to get Aprilaire 600 working?

Tags: electrical, furnace, humidifier

I just replaced an old Aprilaire with a new 600 model. I wired up all the previous wires to the corresponding spots on the new controller, but there are still open spots and when I turned power back on, the Aprilaire controller screen turned on, but it isn’t triggering the water when I turn on the test. Also the controller doesn’t say that the humidifier is on. I had the furnace running when testing.

Attached are the images of the new controller with the attached wires. You’ll see the extra wires that are wrapped around the white sheathing which is coming from the furnace. These weren’t connected to the last Aprilaire and I suspect need to be connected. Appreciate any direction.

Furnace wiring info:
There are two small wires coming in.  The yellow and white wires go to a “Y”.  Another white one goes to a W-1.  A red one goes to “R”.  Green wire goes to green.

Another white wire coming in goes to the Y and the red goes to C.

[image: Controller turned on]

[image: Close up of the wiring connection]

[image: Wiring inside furnace 1]

[image: Wiring inside furnace 2]

[image: Wiring inside furnace 3]

[image: Wiring inside furnace 4]

[image: Aprilaire wiring diagram]

[image: Close up of Furnace wires]

Comment: please trim the wires ... you should not see bare copper when the stripped ends of the wires are inserted into the terminal strip ... the way you have it, you are only asking for accidental short circuits

Comment: Can you post photos of how things are hooked up at the furnace end?

Comment: Add the make/model of all devices involved - furnace, humidifier, etc.

Comment: Aprilaire 600 is the humidifier. The Furnace is a Daikin DM96VE. I'm working on getting a pic of the wires connecting to the furnace

Comment: Updated with more pics and wiring info

Comment: Can you get a closeup of the terminal strip on the furnace board please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel just added a close up. Let me know if that helps or if you need a different view.

Comment: @coreyg -- it appears there is no connection from the humidifier to the furnace as I do not see that cable landing at the furnace terminal block at all (just the thermostat and condenser cables).  Is there some sort of intermediate junction where they connect together at?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Not necessarily seeing a junction. I found out my friend has a similar setup so I’m doing a comparison to see what the differences are between our setups and see if I can narrow in on the differences.